# ORACLE SQL: select multiple rows basd on different values in one column for a same key value in another column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

For example, I want to fetch a list of students who were enrolled in all the 4 semesters of MARCH, JUNE, SEPTEMBER, and NOVEMBER.  But, I do not want to select students who missed enrolment in any of the above months and also were enrolled in semesters other than the above 4.

## ENROLMENT_TABLE

```
STUDENT_NAME    SEMESTER
------------    --------

John            MAR  
Christine       NOV  
John            SEP  
Nicholas        JAN  
John            JUN  
John            NOV  
Linda           MAR  
Christine       SEP  
Linda           SEP  
Nicholas        MAR  
Linda           JUN  
Linda           NOV
```

The required results set are:
A)

```
Student_Name    Semester  
------------    --------  
John            MAR  
John            JUN  
John            SEP  
John            NOV  
Linda           MAR  
Linda           JUN  
Linda           SEP  
Linda           NOV
```

B)

```
% STUDENT ENROLLED IN 4 SEMESTERS    % STUDENT ENROLLED IN 2 SEMESTERS     % STUDENT ENROLLED IN 1 SEMESTERS  
-------------------------            ---------------------------------     -------------------------  
50                                   30                                     20
```

What will be efficient SQL or PL/SQL for the above two outputs A and B?

Answer (score 1):

```
select  sum(case when semesters = 1 then 1 else else 0 end ) / count(*) as Pct_Students_enrolled_1, 
    sum(case when semesters = 2 then 1 else else 0 end ) / count(*) as Pct_Students_enrolled_2
    sum(case when semesters = 4 then 1 else else 0 end ) / count(*) as Pct_Students_enrolled_4
from (
    select  student_name , count(*) as semesters
    from    enrolment_table
    group by student_name );
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the combination (student_name, semester) is unique then you can do this:

```
    SELECT student_name, semester 
        FROM enrolment_table e
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enrolment_table 
               WHERE student_name = e.student_name 
               AND semester in ('MAR', 'JUN', 'SEP', 'NOV'))=4
```

Comment: Ok, I have build my SQL like below. But, it is running for indefinite time and not returning with any result. any idea what is wrong in my SQL.

Comment: SELECT  e.student_OEN,
        e.student_legal_given_name,
        e.student_legal_last_name,
        e.semester
from    edcs_cer.Cstat_ENROLMENT_DATA e
WHERE   (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM  edcs_cer.cstat_enrolment_data b
               WHERE b.student_legal_last_name = e.student_legal_last_name
               AND   b.student_legal_given_name = E.student_legal_given_name
               AND   b.semester in ('MAR', 'JUN', 'SEP', 'NOV'))=4   
               /*AND ROWNUM < 1000*/
order by e.student_oen, e.student_legal_last_name, e.student_legal_given_name;

Comment: what is student_OEN? if it's primary key, why don't you join that also. Please join table on pk.

Comment: Student_OEN is supposed to be the primary key.  But, the problem is that there are duplicate OEN exist for different students.  However, considering that OEN is the PK, what will be the modified SQL.  I think the SQL you gave is right, but somehow my SQL is going in indefinite loop.